# Blank Developer in Visual Basic Editor

Tags: excel, vba, macos

[image]

Hey there, so I am trying self-teach VBA and I clicked some button on my developer window which caused a grey screen (see screen shot above). How do I restore my developer tab to the way it should be?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Visual Basic, but it looks like you don't have any projects or files open, hence the grey background. Just need to open something I think :)

Comment: The project files are open :( I accidentally clicked something and then bam grey screen. I exited and re-open, same problem

Comment: maybe try re-installing it

Comment: When that grey window is active click on View Menu and click the "Project Explorer", "Properties Window" and "Immediate Window". Alternatively try and press ^+CMD+R or ^+CMD+G

Comment: BTW which Excel version is this? It doesn't look like Excel 2011. Is this the latest version?

Comment: What is "some button"?

Comment: So yes this is excel 2016 and actually it was a a problem with minimizing the window

Comment: see the comment that I posted above. You can directly press the key combination or use the menu to unhide them :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try opening the project window to see the sheets that are available, it's the 4th button to the right of the play button on the top tool bar. You may also try Cmd+R.